# How to use LivuLib with Xcode project

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to publish the live video from iphone camera to wowza server. During search I found, that this might be possible with LivuLib library. But don't know how to use this. Anyone have any idea on this or other alternative way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use  http://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore and also https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x to stream to YouTube. I think Wowza would be similar.